# Ajax Loading graphic while waiting for d3 graphs/.json response? (Rails)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, d3.js

I am loading multiple d3 line graphs in a Ruby on Rails app and want to display a loading image (gif) while I wait for my data response to populate them.

What's the best, easiest way to do this? Should I place some jQuery inside my Ajax call or before it, perhaps?

I send a ajax request for some .json and draw the graphs in a .js file that looks like this:

my_d3_file.js:

```
var loadData = function () {  
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var site_id = path[path.length - 1];
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: '/data_reports.json?site_id=' + site_id + '&graphable=true',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          drawGraphs(data)
      },
      failure: function (result) {
          error();
      }
});

function drawGraphs(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#plot1").append("svg")...
    // etc, code for d3 graphs
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();
})
```

My html looks like this:

my_graphs.html.erb

```
 <div id="plot1" class="plot"></div>
```

My Rails file structure looks like this:

```
assets
    images
        my_loading_image.gif
    javascripts
        my_d3_file.js
    stylesheets
        my_css.css
views
    graph_folder
        my_graphs.html.erb
```

Does something like this get me started? I'm just not sure where everything needs to be placed, specifically in my JavaScript file, in relation to the ajax call.

Inside ("#plot1"):

```
<img src="../../assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading-gif" 
style="display:none" />
//also, is my file path correct?
```

In my css:

```
  #loading-indicator {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
     top: 10px;
   }
```

In my_d3_file.js:

```
 $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    $('#loading-gif').show();
  });


 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    $('#loading-gif').hide();
 });
```

Thanks so much! Let me know if I can provide more info!

Comment: The thing with that is that (assuming you are using the rails defaults) every time you send an ajax request, you will execute the `$(document).ajaxSend()` and `$(document).ajaxComplete()`  functions. This might be a problem later.

Comment: Ah I see. Is that because it can interfere with other ajax requests?

Comment: Not "interfere". But if in your application you are performing any other AJAX call, those two functions are going to be executed because of those AJAX calls.  This may or not be a problem later

Comment: @LaurenAH Not related to your question, but why are you mixing jQuery and D3? You don't need that mix! Use D3 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the spinner graphic inside the `#plot1` tag

```
<div id="plot1" class="plot">
    <img src="../../assets/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
```

At the time you want to draw your graph here just select the image and remove it, and create an `svg` tag instead

```
d3.select("#plot1 img").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#plot1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
```

Just add your drawing to this `svg` variable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps, in your ajax call use the `beforeSend` callback to display the loading gif, and in your `success` callback hide them and render the graphs. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend. function() {
    aFunctionToShowLoadingGIF();
  },
  success: function (data) {
    aFunctionToHideTheLoadingGIF();
    drawGraphs(data);
  }
  failure: function (result) {
    error();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a div with loader.  Don't initially hide it.

```
<div id='loader'><img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>
```

Then hide the loader once the data is loaded by d3.

```
    // load the d3 data
    d3.json("json/data.json", function(treeData) {
        $("#loader").hide();
//rest of code
}
```

Show the loader div again if you need to reload the data elsewhere.